# How can I get EasyOCR return 0 or empty string

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr

I have this image and EasyOcr can recognize the numbers normally

[image]

But I want to get the empty spaces too, how can I make an empty string return or something that tells me there's no number there, is there any method that does that?

My code is like this for now

```
import cv2 as cv
import easyocr

reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])

defaultImage = cv.imread('numeros.png')
defaultImage = defaultImage[100:570]
greyImage = cv.cvtColor(defaultImage, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cv.imwrite('newGrey.png', greyImage)

text = reader.readtext('newGrey.png', detail=0)

#print(text)
```

Comment: you may need to split image to smaller regions and then check every region

Comment: if you can consider tesseract -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61250577/how-to-preserve-all-whitespaces-from-an-image-when-doing-text-extraction-using-t

Answer (score 0):

You can do some image processing to find coordinates of rows and columns on the image. After you get result from easyOCR, you can map result to rows and colums by its bounding boxes. In finally, you can make spaces by empty columns on the table.