# Is reading the text from this type of image doable? If so, how would I approach doing it?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, python-tesseract

I think that most OCR tools are used for reading documents.
I'm trying to make a program that reads the post-result screen from a game.
I was wondering if it's possible using some sort of workaround (I'm new to OCR tools).

An [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vUQS.jpg) of the image.

A simple program I tried using from the internet:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\\Users\\labib\\AppData\\Local\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'

img = cv2.imread('test2.png')

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(text)
```

I then tried different thresholds, and tried grayscaling but it didn't change the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUd3Y.png) that much.

I then thought about making a function that would first crop the image into a table and read the values from the cells of the columns instead? I don't know if that would make it easier on the OCR tool.

Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cbkX.png).
I would then put the data from the image into a spreadsheet (which I think I can do)

**My question is**, how would I approach reading an image that is not a document and is difficult to read. (*my current issue is reading the text on the image itself*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is similar to this question [Preserving indentation with Tesseract OCR 4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59582008/preserving-indentation-with-tesseract-ocr-4-x)

You can try this code. It can output most of what you want. To really fit your need, you must filter unnecessary icon, image, etc.

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output
import pandas as pd

img = cv2.imread("sxFRauD.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
gauss = cv2.GaussianBlur(thresh, (3, 3), 0)

custom_config = r'-l eng --oem 3 --psm 6 -c preserve_interword_spaces=1 -c tessedit_char_whitelist="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-:. "'
d = pytesseract.image_to_data(gauss, config=custom_config, output_type=Output.DICT)
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# clean up blanks
df1 = df[(df.conf != '-1') & (df.text != ' ') & (df.text != '')]
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

# sort blocks vertically
sorted_blocks = df1.groupby('block_num').first().sort_values('top').index.tolist()
for block in sorted_blocks:
    curr = df1[df1['block_num'] == block]
    sel = curr[curr.text.str.len() > 3]
    # sel = curr
    char_w = (sel.width / sel.text.str.len()).mean()
    prev_par, prev_line, prev_left = 0, 0, 0
    text = ''
    for ix, ln in curr.iterrows():
        # add new line when necessary
        if prev_par != ln['par_num']:
            text += '\n'
            prev_par = ln['par_num']
            prev_line = ln['line_num']
            prev_left = 0
        elif prev_line != ln['line_num']:
            text += '\n'
            prev_line = ln['line_num']
            prev_left = 0

        added = 0  # num of spaces that should be added
        if ln['left'] / char_w > prev_left + 1:
            added = int((ln['left']) / char_w) - prev_left
            text += ' ' * added
        text += ln['text'] + ' '
        prev_left += len(ln['text']) + added + 1
    text += '\n'
    print(text)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

```
           POST-ACTION REPORT 
           CUSTOM GAME                                             0:04                                                            e 
           MATCH     SCOREBOARD 
                   DEFEAT                                                             Y        Oo      j8     kK     al 
                      MM      Zz  ezswims.ENMU                               a       2188       6      0      8      52 
                               a  Shiro.ENMU                                 8       2040       4      4      8      52 
                               SH RubbaDucky.ENMU                       t            1721       3      1      9      44 
                                  ICEDrgon29.ENMU                            a       1710       3      0      8      69 
                               3  Gongshow.ENMU                              a       1375       1      1      8      56 
                               2  Nemesis.ERAU                                       4930       9      3      2      41 
                               2   Phantom.ERAU                                      4895       9      3      4      50 
                      7        2  Reggie.ERAU                                        4630       6      o      2      80 
                                2  D4NG3RZON3.ERAU                                   4510       6      1      5      53
```

Answer (score 0):

Before calling image_to_string try:

```
 img=cv2.bitwise_not(img)
```