# text recognition and restructuring OCR opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, ocr

Link to original image
https://ibb.co/0VC6vkX

I am currently working with an OCR Project. I pre-processed the image, and then applied pre-trained EAST model for text detection.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from imutils.object_detection import non_max_suppression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

img=cv2.imread('bw_image.jpg')
model=cv2.dnn.readNet('frozen_east_text_detection.pb')

#Prepare the Image
#use multiple of 32 to set the new image shape
height,width,colorch=img.shape
new_height=(height//32)*32
new_width=(width//32)*32
print(new_height,new_width)

h_ratio=height/new_height
w_ratio=width/new_width
print(h_ratio,w_ratio)

#blob from image helps us to prepare the image
blob=cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img,1,(new_width,new_height),(123.68,116.78,103.94),True, False)
model.setInput(blob)

#this model outputs geometry and score maps
(geometry,scores)=model.forward(model.getUnconnectedOutLayersNames())

#once we have done geometry and score maps we have to do post processing to obtain the final text boxes
rectangles=[]
confidence_score=[]
for i in range(geometry.shape[2]):
    for j in range(0,geometry.shape[3]):
    
        if scores[0][0][i][j]<0.1:
            continue

        bottom_x=int(j*4 + geometry[0][1][i][j])
        bottom_y=int(i*4 + geometry[0][2][i][j])

        top_x=int(j*4 - geometry[0][3][i][j])
        top_y=int(i*4 - geometry[0][0][i][j])

        rectangles.append((top_x,top_y,bottom_x,bottom_y))
        confidence_score.append(float(scores[0][0][i][j]))

#use nms to get required triangles
final_boxes=non_max_suppression(np.array(rectangles),probs=confidence_score,overlapThresh=0.5)

#finally to display these text boxes let's iterate over them and convert them to the original shape 
#using the ratio we calculated earlier
img_copy=img.copy()

for (x1,y1,x2,y2) in final_boxes:
    
    x1=int(x1*w_ratio)
    y1=int(y1*h_ratio)
    x2=int(x2*w_ratio)
    y2=int(y2*h_ratio)
    
    #to draw the rectangles on the image use cv2.rectangle function
    cv2.rectangle(img_copy,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)
```

This gives us the detected text as follows:
[image]

Now for text recognition I used pre-trained opencv CRNN model as follows:

```
# Download the CRNN model and Load it
model1 = cv2.dnn.readNet('D:/downloads/crnn.onnx')


# ## Prepare the image
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img_gray, scalefactor=1/127.5, size=(100,32), mean=127.5)


# Pass the image to network and extract per-timestep scores
model1.setInput(blob)

scores = model1.forward()
print(scores.shape)

alphabet_set = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
blank = '-'

char_set = blank + alphabet_set


# Decode the scores to text
def most_likely(scores, char_set):
    text = ""
    for i in range(scores.shape[0]):
        c = np.argmax(scores[i][0])
        text += char_set[c]
    return text


def map_rule(text):
    char_list = []
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if i == 0:
            if text[i] != '-':
                char_list.append(text[i])
        else:
            if text[i] != '-' and (not (text[i] == text[i - 1])):
                char_list.append(text[i])
    return ''.join(char_list)


def best_path(scores, char_set):
    text = most_likely(scores, char_set)
    final_text = map_rule(text)
    return final_text


out = best_path(scores, char_set)
print(out)
```

But applying this model on the image gives the following output:

```
saetan
```

I really don't understand it. Can anyone guide what is the problem with text recognition. Is there a problem with pre-trained CRNN model? Moreover, I also want to restructure the text after it has been recognized, they way it is structured in the original image. We have the bounding box coordinates and recognised text after recognition problem is solved, so how can we restructure the text exactly? Any help will be appreciated.

Edit: I used pytesseract `image_to_string()` and `image_to_data()` functions but they don't give that good performance. Is there any other pre-trained text recognition model that I can use so that I can replicate the success of my `EAST Text Detection` model if this CRNN model is not fit enough. So that I can restructure my text accurately as it is in the image with the help of `coordinates(bounding boxes)` obtained through EAST Model.

Comment: Is it a must to use the EAST model (`crnn.onnx`) for text detection? If not, I would recommend using `pytesseract`. Specifically the `image_to_string()` and `image_to_data()` functions.

Comment: I have tried `pytesseract` and the functions that you mentioned but they don't give that accurate results. Maybe that is due to the reason that pytesseract doesn't work very well with low quality images. I preferred EAST model and CRNN pre-trained model, because as shown in the image EAST model detected text quite accurately and I want to replicate that success in text recognition too.

Comment: Did you apply `pytesseract` on the whole image or on single bounding boxes? I usually only use `pytesseract` after having retrieved bounding boxes, but then performance is generally really well. Your image is not of bad enough quality for `pytesseract` to fail IMO. Maybe try some [more preprocessing](https://nanonets.com/blog/ocr-with-tesseract/#preprocessingfortesseract). Your bounding boxes are really constraining also, the letters need to be fully inside the box for OCR to work. Maybe try to add some padding pixles.

Comment: quick question ... is the size in the second code snippet from the `blobFromImage` function assigned from the bounding boxes? I applied tesseract to some of the boxes from the image you provided (with some preprocessing like thresholding, morphological transformation ... ), most of the time it performs fairly well, some of the words were not detected fully which can be fixed by cross-matching to a dictionary.

Comment: @ParsaRahimi size in the `blobFromImage` is the pre-defined default parameter that we use in CRNN pre-trained model. I looked that one up on the internet.

Comment: You need to porvide `CRNN` (or `pytesseract`) the detected _bounding boxes_ (one at a time, I suspect) not the entire image. You need to loop over all boxes.

Comment: Kindly provide the original input image by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67763853/edit) your question accordingly.

Comment: @HansHirse added the original input image

Comment: I think the better way to rephrase my question would be on how to loop over the bounding boxes detected through East Model and recognize the text in those bounding boxes as suggested by @Shai

Comment: Give it a try -- KerasOCR

Comment: @Junaid, community members here spend considerable time and effort to solve other member's problems, so it would be a nice gesture if you could respond to their answers and/or comments. Especially the ones that propose a solution to your problem.

Comment: I have already added a solution that does exactly what you asked for in you rephrased question. So, in that sense, my solution is what you were looking for. And yes, you are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Processing crops is really simple, just change a little your last loop:

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

...
 
for x1,y1,x2,y2 in final_boxes:
        
    #to draw the rectangles on the image use cv2.rectangle function
    # cv2.rectangle(img_copy,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)
    img_crop = Image.fromarray(img[y1-1: y2+1, x1-1:x2+1])
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img_crop, config='--psm 8').strip()
    cv2.putText(img_copy, text, (x1,y1), 0, .7, (0, 0, 255), 2 )
```

[image]

Comment: that does solve my problem without having to use pre-trained crnn model. Can you kindly guide me to restructure this recognised text on some word or pdf file, the way it is structured in the above receipt.

Comment: You can see my other answer, dealing exactly with the issue of [preserving indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59582008/preserving-indentation-with-tesseract-ocr-4-x/59666326#59666326). Sort your boxes vertically and left to right, then apply the code.

Comment: @Junaid, the answer you accepted is what I had written as a comment to my first solution. You clearly wrote after this that you needed a solution for CRNN, and that's what I provided you as my second answer.

Answer (score 1):

After careful examination I see that your code has quite a few problems. If I understand how you would like to run crnn recognizer then following solution might solve your problem.

Your function definitions:

```
# Decode the scores to text
def most_likely(scores, char_set):
    text = ""
    for i in range(scores.shape[0]):
        c = np.argmax(scores[i][0])
        text += char_set[c]
    return text


def map_rule(text):
    char_list = []
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if i == 0:
            if text[i] != '-':
                char_list.append(text[i])
        else:
            if text[i] != '-' and (not (text[i] == text[i - 1])):
                char_list.append(text[i])
    return ''.join(char_list)


def best_path(scores, char_set):
    text = most_likely(scores, char_set)
    final_text = map_rule(text)
    return final_text
```

Most of the following code is what you already had, compare for changes:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from imutils.object_detection import non_max_suppression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

img=cv2.imread('/path/to/your_imge.jpeg')
model=cv2.dnn.readNet('/path/to/frozen_east_text_detection.pb')

#Prepare the Image
#use multiple of 32 to set the new image shape
height,width,colorch=img.shape
new_height=(height//32)*32
new_width=(width//32)*32
print(new_height,new_width)

h_ratio=height/new_height
w_ratio=width/new_width
print(h_ratio,w_ratio)

#blob from image helps us to prepare the image
blob=cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img,1,(new_width,new_height),(123.68,116.78,103.94),True, False)
model.setInput(blob)

#this model outputs geometry and score maps
(geometry,scores)=model.forward(model.getUnconnectedOutLayersNames())

#once we have done geometry and score maps we have to do post processing to obtain the final text boxes
rectangles=[]
confidence_score=[]
for i in range(geometry.shape[2]):
    for j in range(0,geometry.shape[3]):
    
        if scores[0][0][i][j]<0.1:
            continue

        bottom_x=int(j*4 + geometry[0][1][i][j])
        bottom_y=int(i*4 + geometry[0][2][i][j])

        top_x=int(j*4 - geometry[0][3][i][j])
        top_y=int(i*4 - geometry[0][0][i][j])

        rectangles.append((top_x,top_y,bottom_x,bottom_y))
        confidence_score.append(float(scores[0][0][i][j]))

#use nms to get required triangles
final_boxes=non_max_suppression(np.array(rectangles),probs=confidence_score,overlapThresh=0.5)

model1 = cv2.dnn.readNet('/path/to/crnn.onnx')


# ## Prepare the image
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

alphabet_set = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
blank = '-'

char_set = blank + alphabet_set

for (x1,y1,x2,y2) in final_boxes:
    
    x1=int(x1*w_ratio)
    y1=int(y1*h_ratio)
    x2=int(x2*w_ratio)
    y2=int(y2*h_ratio)
    
    # Work with detected text boxes for recognition
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img_gray[y1:y2, x1:x2], scalefactor=1/127.5, size=(100,32), mean=127.5)

    # Pass the image to network and extract per-timestep scores
    model1.setInput(blob)

    scores = model1.forward()
    print(scores.shape)

    out = best_path(scores, char_set)
    print(out)
```

You might have to overlay the recognized text on top of the image or so to check for accuracy. There are better ways to do the testing but that's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: @Junaid, does the code work the way you want? I am sure accuracy could be an issue but it should at least iterate over all the detected text boxes and print recognized characters.

Comment: Yes it does work, but displays recognized characters one by one, which is not a wrong approach, but I was looking for a more robust approach. And yes you gave the answer in the comment of your other answer, but I was not sure how to do it. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution that you can try improving on by trying a few things:

- by varying Gaussian parameters
- by thresholding the blurred image to see if it improves the result

Code:

```
gray = cv2.imread('/path/to/your_image.jpeg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

g = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), .5)

config = "-l eng --oem 1 --psm 6"
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(g, config=config)
print(text)
```

Resulting text (partial):

```
400242 | 6161108006012 BIO WHOLE MILK 1LTR \ 1PCS 12.Cu PCS 430.50 1,566.00
400365 | 6161108000119 BIO YOG VANILLA 150ML CUP ! 1PCS 24.05 PCS 91.02 2,184.36
400545 | 6161108000584 BIO LONG LIFE COOKING CREAM SOOML 1 1PCS \ 12.Gu PCS 241.32 2,895.78
74 - i :
400821 | 6161108005060" | BIO YOGHURT STRAWBERRY 450ML | 1Pcs 6.50 PCS 266.37 1,598.23
400822 , 6161108005207 BIO YOGHURT VANILLA 90ML ; 1PCS ! 36.0b FCS 60.96 2,194.38
450466 | 6166000051801 KENTASTE COCONUT MILK 400ML ; 1CTN * 12 PCS | 2.00 TN 1,920.96 3,841.92
, 450469 | 6166000051818 KENTASTE COCONUT CREAM 400ML : 1CTN* 12 PCS | 2.0. CTN 2,213.28 4,426.56
450465 | 6166000051887 KENTASTE COCONUT OIL 700ML 1CTN * 12 PCS | Iso) STN) 7,697.76 7,697.76
400985 | 6161108000812 BIO WHOLE MILK LONG LIFE SOOML EPCS: 12.00 PCS | 67.40 808.79
```

Comment: I have used pytesseract and it returns pretty good results without using Gaussian Blur as compared to yours. I think the better way to rephrase my question would be on how to loop over the bounding boxes detected through East Model and recognise the text in those bounding boxes.

Comment: Can you just not run the pytesserect on the bounding box images in your for loop? What's wrong with that approach? In my tests slightly blurring the image gave me better results.

Comment: In any case, slightly preprocessing your test image is definitely going to improve the results.

Comment: @Junaid, the answer you accepted is what I had written here as a solution (see my second comment). You clearly wrote after this that you needed a solution for CRNN, and that's what I provided you.